# Why does the linux kernel contain pairs of functions that differ only by an __ prefix?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

The Linux scheduler forking operation uses two function `sched_fork()` and `__sched_fork()`. `__sched_fork()` is called by `sched_fork()`. Similar code conventions with double underscore ( specifically used for system reserved name) are used in several other places in the kernel. How does defining two functions like this help, when one function could have been used? Why is this convention used?

Answer (score 4):

Historically, the pattern was to make the __function be the function that does the 'guts' of an operation, with an absolute minimum of argument checking. The no-__ function, on the other hand, would have some checks for parameter validity, or some other extra-cost operations. However, sometimes, it's just a modularity split into 'the very middle' and 'the rest'.

Answer (score 2):

If you search sources, you will see that `__sched_fork()` is called from `init_idle()` as well as from `sched_fork()`. I think that it's a primary reason for defining two functions.

I also see pairs of functions (with and without `__`) with different implementations. For example, `__hrtick_start()` and `hrtick_start()`. However, they have slightly different usage: the first one should be called from hardirqs.

Other pairs may be separated when version with underscores does the core work of function and version without underscores does additional tests before invoking it. In that way, programmer can call underscored version if all conditions are already checked.